# Indicating missing data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nan

### Update

So I have been playing around with this, and it seems that this actually happens when I read a different csv file into my program using `read_csv()`. And what then happens is exactly what the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) say will happen:

> By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: ‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘nan’.

So my bad for not considering this step in my code; thanks to everyone who helped out.

---

### Original question

I'm creating spreadsheets in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) by filling columns with the string "NA" (`spreadsheet['name']="NA"`) and then incrementally replacing those "NA"s with actual datapoints.
Here is how I do that: `spreadsheet.loc[spread[match row number here], =inputstring.split("\t")`

When outputting the data with [`.to_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), I was surprised to find out that pandas apparently interprets these "NA" strings to indicate missing data, e.g. it replaces them with whatever I feed into `na_rep=`. I was mainly using the "NA"s as placeholders and did not expect pandas (which outputs missing data as "Nan") to mess with them.

I could not find anything on the matter in the [documentation on missing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html), where they create NaNs with `np.nan`

Thus,

- Is it correct that Pandas will just interpret a string "NA" anywhere in my spreadsheet as "missing data"? Do they do some kind of string matching?
- If so, what other strings can be used that way? Or what would be the most legit way of representing missing data points?
- If true, this behavior seems kinda dangerous to me / can lead to unexpected behavior. Or is this not true?

Any help / pointers to the relevant resources are much appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you run `.to_csv()` on something like `DataFrame({"A": ["NA", "NA", "NA"]})`? I'm curious because I can't recreate the behavior you're describing.

Comment: tanks for your input, that does indeed not reproduce! Good point, I wonder where I went astray - all I'm doing to it afterward is adding datapoints like this: `spreadsheet.loc[spreadsheet[match row number here], =inputstring.split("\t") `

Answer (score 0):

You can try it this way:

```
spreadsheet = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']})
spreadsheet
    name
0   NA
1   NA
2   NA
3   NA
4   NA
```

Then if you want to replace a couple of the `NA`s you can just select where you want to replace them.

```
spreadsheet.loc[1:2] = 'foo'
spreadsheet
    name
0   NA
1   foo
2   foo
3   NA
4   NA
```